# JSColor Picker rendering grey box instead of color matrix

Tags: javascript, css, jscolor

I'm using jscolor picker and it's choosing the color just fine, but it doesn't show the colors, just a grey box like below.  When I mouseover the grey area however, the color and hex changes.  Any ideas what could be wrong?  I've tried both Safari and Chrome (mac) to see if it was browser related, but same behavior in both.

The code is standard too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/jscolor.js"></script>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="pg/background_hex" ID="pg/background_hex" VALUE="" SIZE=25 MAXLENGTH=100 class='color'>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="pg/foreground_hex" ID="pg/foreground_hex" VALUE="" SIZE=25 MAXLENGTH=100 class='color'>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Your code appears to work fine on their demo http://jscolor.com/try.php

Comment: Does the code require an image? Possibly the browser can't load the image.

Comment: Yes!  I was missing the image Joshua.  Found the answer immediately after clicking Post Question!  Thanks Joshua!